# Inserting data into a SQL server from an excel file

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

First of all, sorry for my lack of knowledge regarding databases, this is my first time working with them.

I am having some issues trying to get the data from an excel file and putting it into a data base.

Using answers from the site, I managed to kind of connect to the database by doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

server = 'XXXXX'
db = 'XXXXXdb'

# create Connection and Cursor objects
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# read data from excel
data = pd.read_excel('data.csv')
```

But I dont really know what to do now.

I have 3 tables, which are connected by a 'productID', my excel file mimics the data base, meaning that all the columns in the excel file have a place to go in the DB.

My plan was to read the excel file and make lists with each column, then insert into the DB each column value but I have no idea how to create a query that can do this.

Once I get the query I think the data insertion can be done like this:

```
query = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

for row in data:
    #The following is not the real code
    productID = productID
    name = name
    url = url

    values = (productID, name, url)

    cursor.execute(query,values)

conn.commit()
conn.close
```

Database looks like this.

https://prnt.sc/n2d2fm

http://prntscr.com/n2d3sh

http://prntscr.com/n2d3yj

EDIT:

Tried doing something like this, but i'm getting 'not all arguments converted during string formatting' Type error.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

connStr = pymysql.connect(host = 'xx.xxx.xx.xx', port = xxxx, user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx') 

df = pd.read_csv('GenericProducts.csv')

cursor = connStr.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO [Productos]([ItemID],[Nombre])) values (?,?)"

for index,row in df.iterrows():

    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Productos([ItemID],[Nombre])) values (?,?,?)", row['codigoEspecificoProducto'], row['nombreProducto'])
    codigoEspecificoProducto = row['codigoEspecificoProducto']
    nombreProducto = row['nombreProducto']

    values = (codigoEspecificoProducto,nombreProducto)

    cursor.execute(query,values)


connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```

I think my problem is in how I'm defining the query, surely thats not the right way

Comment: https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/using-python-pandas-dataframe-to-read-and-insert-data-to-microsoft-sql-server/ try this

Comment: Tried it and it seems the way to go, getting new errors though, will edit the question with new info

Comment: you have (?,?,?) but are inserting only two values

Comment: Changed it to (?,?) but im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you seem to have changed the library from pyodbc to mysql, it seems to expect %s instead of ?

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

connStr = pymysql.connect(host = 'xx.xxx.xx.xx', port = xxxx, user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx') 

df = pd.read_csv('GenericProducts.csv')

cursor = connStr.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO [Productos]([ItemID],[Nombre]) values (%s,%s)"

for index,row in df.iterrows():

    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Productos([ItemID],[Nombre]) values (%s,%s)", row['codigoEspecificoProducto'], row['nombreProducto'])
    codigoEspecificoProducto = row['codigoEspecificoProducto']
    nombreProducto = row['nombreProducto']

    values = (codigoEspecificoProducto,nombreProducto)

    cursor.execute(query,values)


connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```