# Arguments converted TypeError while inserting data into DB with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Found some questions regarding this topic but none of them really solved my problem.

I'm running into some issues while trying to insert data into my SQL server, I'm pretty new in regards of Databases so my guess is that there is something wrong with how I defined the query or the values.

My code looks like this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO `Productos`(`IDProductos`, `ItemID`, `Nombre`, `MPN`, `Descripcion`, `URL`, `Precio`, `Departamento`, `CodigoGenerico`, `Fecha`, `Procedencia`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

for index,row in df.iterrows():

    IDProductos = '???'
    ItemID = row['codigoEspecificoProducto']
    Nombre = row['nombreProducto']
    MPN = 'null'
    Descripcion = 'null'
    URL = row['urlProducto']
    Precio = row ['precioProducto']
    Departamento = row['categoriaProducto']
    CodigoGenerico = row['codigoGenericoProducto']
    Fecha = 'null'
    Procedencia = 'Amazon'

    values = [IDProductos,ItemID,Nombre,MPN,Descripcion,URL,Precio,Departamento,CodigoGenerico,Fecha,Procedencia]

    cursor.execute(query,values)
```

What I'm doing is basically passing data from an excel file to my database.

Is the query I'm ussing correct? It's the one I got from copying the `insert` that appears in the database.

I get the `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` when it reaches `cursor.execute(query,values)`

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server. Your query appears to be mysql syntax. Why do you tag both?

Comment: Sorry, the DB was made by a friend for me to use, I don't have any experience at all with databases. Will fix the question now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting data into a SQL server from an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328732/inserting-data-into-a-sql-server-from-an-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

From Excel to SQL Server.

' Set a reference to: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=Your_Server_Name"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```